# DB Transaction in Controllers

Tags: php, transactions, zend-framework2

I have created a crud system. Here I have a main model and then dependent details model. So their are multiple rows (some times > 100 ) entered into details model related to parent model. All operations handled through grid ( inline edit ). So create, update, delete operations are performed through single request (logical checking via DB).

Now I am considering to use DB transaction to whole operations. But I am confused, how I can implement this using same structure. I already have suggestions to move my all code to one model, So transaction can be applied there. But I am thinking, if any other approach can be used for retain separation of main and details model code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for my last comment, Moving code to parent model is my solution for now. So I think I should mark this thread answered.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AJAX for the changes or does it rely on manual form submissions?

You can use what's called a UnitOfWork pattern.

Save any changes that the user makes to each line of the grid but don't actually commit them to the DB. Then, place a geneic save button on the page that will cause your server to actually commit all the changes through a transaction.

You can keep a list server side of each row that the user changes. You don't need to track all the rows because if they don't change anything you don't need to save anything.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of approach are you using in your Models?  Do your models know about their own persistence (do you do things like `$user->save()`), or are you doing a more data-mapper approach (`$userManager->save($userEntity)`)?  The latter makes transaction handling a lot easier.

If you're doing the active-record type of patter (`$user->save()`), your best bet is probably just to manually grab your db connection and manage the transaction in your controller.

If you're doing data-mapper stuff, you have more options, up to and including doing a whole unit-of-work implementation.

Comment: Well in Zend 2 Framework, we are using so,something like
 $this->update($array, array('id' => $module_details->id)) on SaveModule method in our model. So look like a mixed approach compare to Zend 1.

Comment: I have just moved my details model save method call from controller to parent model after save . Look like it is only simple solution I have :).